# Convert position of a person to other coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, coordinate-systems, rotations

In an installation, I'm tracking persons with a Kinect camera. Another device, positioned in the range of the camera, should now look towards the direction of the person. This is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAJNv.png).

By knowing the position of the origin and rotation of the coordinate system of the other device in respect to the coordinate system of the Kinect, am I able to convert the **Position P_*Kinect*** to **Position P_*Other Device***? If so, how?

Comment: The $z$ coordinate can  be neglected in your case?

Comment: For simplicity reasons I left it out. I might add z in a later version of the prototype, but right now it's only about x and y.